# Extract numbers between square bracket and separated by comma

Tags: java, regex

I have an input file:

```
U10:%x[-2,1]
U11:%x[-1,1]
U12:%x[0,1]q
U13:%x[1,1]
U14:%x[2,1]
U15:%x[-2,1]/%x[-1,1]
U16:%x[-1,1]/%x[0,1]
U17:%x[0,1]/%x[1,1]
U18:%x[1,1]/%x[2,1]

U20:%x[-2,1]/%x[-1,1]/%x[0,1]
U21:%x[-1,1]/%x[0,1]/%x[1,1]
U22:%x[0,1]/%x[1,1]/%x[2,1]
```

Now I want to read line by line and extract the number to assign to variable `i,j` such that:

```
i=-2, j=1;
i=-1, j=1;
i=0, j=1;
i=1, j=1;
i=2, j=1;
i=-2, j=1; then i=-1, j=1;
i=-1, j=1; then i=0, j=1;
etc.
```

I am thinking about regular expressions, but strangely this one give no match:

```
FileReader frr = new FileReader("/Users/home/Documents/input.txt");
BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(frr);
String linee;

while ((linee = brr.readLine()) != null) {
    String pattern = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);               
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(linee);                
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
}
brr.close();
```

And if I use split, it also return very strange results:

```
String[] listItems = linee.replaceFirst("^\\[", "").split("(\\(\\d+\\))?\\]?(\\s*,\\s*\\[?|$)");
System.out.println(listItems);
```

result:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@c3bb2b8
```

etc.

How should I do the above task?

Comment: Well, you're printing out the raw array.  Use `Array.toString(regexMatcher.group())` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should switch up your regular expression to capture the two integers inside the brackets. After that you can use `regexMatcher.find()` and iterate through all the matches to get the ints.

Example

```
String pattern = "\\[(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\]";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
while (regexMatcher.find()){
    int i = Integer.valueOf(regexMatcher.group(1));
    int j = Integer.valueOf(regexMatcher.group(2));
    ...
}
```

This will get you `i` and `j` for each matching group.

Comment: Yes, it works for positive case! But look like it cannot extract the negative number...

Comment: changed to support negative numbers